# Reverse-engineering frequent interlockedIncrement/Decrement

Tags: visual-c++, reverse-engineering, interlocked

I'm trying to reverse engineer some code and run into a common pattern many times, but I'm not sure what could it be. The code was compiled with VC++ 2010 and uses some external CLR components for display (but not for any internals as far as I can tell).

Some pattern I see is in some functions that return an object is that they either:

- do a `InterlockedIncrement` on `obj_ptr - 12` before returning it
- check the result of `InterlockedDecrement` on `obj_ptr - 12` and if the result is 0, call `*(*(obj_ptr - 24) + 64)(obj_ptr - 24)`

It looks like some GC based on reference counting with eager call to the destructor. Can anyone confirm if this is correct, or is it some other system?

If that's right - is there some known interface I can see? I'd like to know if I can assume the places doing Increment before returning the value can be assumed to be some expanded version of 'new' for that type.

Also, where could I find more information about this? It looks like this cannot be a part of the standard object's vtable which I'd expect to be a short pointer at the front. Maybe RTTI... but I couldn't find any good example of its layout. I don't expect any multiple inheritance here that would move the base class further in.

Comment: That's what shared_ptr<> does.  Reference count, delete on 0.

Comment: Oh - I expected it to be something simple :) Never dealt much with c++.

Comment: This article does mention that offset -12 of the method table refers to a "GCInfo" item, but doesn't discuss it further: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx